# How to stop recompile in eclipse after adding new library

Tags: eclipse, maven

Eclipse recompile everything after I change maven pom file, which makes the performance very bad. How to disable auto-compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project -> Build automatically and turn it off.

Comment: Well, when I change java files, I still expect the IDE help me compile automatically.

Comment: Have you tried it? You still get eclipse compile errors.

Comment: Hi Chris, Yes I did tried. It could cause various issues that I don't expect. For example, it don't auto compile/push the changes to application server during development.